# MVVM design question

Tags: c#, silverlight

I'm trying to create an silverlight application using the MVVM design pattern. It's a kind of bank application.

I've watched a lot of tutorials on MVVM but something makes me real confused.

I have about fiwe usercontrols representing my views "TransactionsView", "AccountView" etc and a bunch of models "UserProfile" - containing user password, username and a list of UserAccounts, "UserAccounts" - containing name, balance and a list of AccountTransactions, "AccountTransactions" - containing a name, and ammount.

Should i create one modelview which contains my userprofile or should i create a viewmodel for every view i have? I'm a doing right so far? Or have i got it completley wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Some useful tips: a) the viewmodel is the servant of the view; create it based on the needs of the view; b) model is very loosely defined, this is mostly just whatever is used by viewmodel for loading/saving data, and any business logic classes; c) viewmodel can also include business logic (e.g. validation rules); d) keep your model lightweight and do not overthink it - the view and viewmodel are the important parts; e) use data binding and ICommands to tie the view and viewmodel together; minimize any direct method calls from view to viewmodel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVVM, ViewModels are usually 1-to-1 with Views.  There isn't a parity between number of ViewModel and Models, though.

- View: UI
- ViewModel: Handles changes to view state, forwarding them to the model if/when appropriate.  Sends notifications from the underlying program back to the user.  It may also do initial UI validation.
- Model: Actual "guts" of the application.  Algorithms, data storage, system calls etc go here.  I put program flow here.  I've seen other people put it in the ViewModel.  That part is up to you to figure out.

A View always needs a ViewModel, hence 1-to-1 (it could have sub-models, but I'll leave that up to you to decide on/deal with.  I'd start off with 1-to-1).

A ViewModel usually needs Models to actually "do work", but how many classes/instances is up to each app/problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Can i use the same ViewModel for two diffrent views? And should I have a global "MainViewModel" which holds public propertys of my other viewmodels so i can access them from where i want?

Comment: @Richard: You can do whatever you want, it is your app :)  Having said that, think of a ViewModel as an ambassador between your UI and your program.  Let the program think in terms of the program, let the UI think in terms of the UI, and let the ViewModel(s) translate.  If you're straying too far from directly handling UI state/UI commands, doing UI input validation, and passing program status back to the UI, then you're probably heading out of ViewModel country, and into Model town.  Without seeing some portion of your app's design, I can't give much more specific advise.

Comment: @Richard: MVVM is fuzzy, though.  You don't have to have 1-to-1.  It's just a good place to start.  I personally prefer to have my ViewModel be more "dumb", though, and let the program flow be dictated by a portion of the model.  Other people place the program flow in the hands of the ViewModel, which is what it sounds like you want to do.  As long as it is quick to program, easy to understand (with as little explanation/few well placed comments as possible), easy to debug/test/ensure is bug-free, and easy to maintain, then you know you're on the right path.

Answer (score 0):

From what you explain you are going in the right direction. What viewmodel you create is a bit up to you, MVVM is not set in stone - its just a method. What I found through trial and ERROR was that it was smart to understand it well before digging myself in too deep.

I read many articles that didn't explain MVVM in a way I could understand. Finally I found a couple of articles by Jeremiah Morrill that were straight to the point and easy to understand: [Article 1](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/432/MVVM-for-Tarded-Folks-Like-Me-or-MVVM-and-What-it-Means-to-Me.aspx) and [article 2](http://jmorrill.hjtcentral.com/Home/tabid/428/EntryId/433/Anatomy-of-an-MVVM-Application-or-How-Tards-Like-Me-Make-MVVM-Apps.aspx).

Comment: Interesting articles. I agree that they present MVVM in a good way.

Answer (score 0):

One ViewModel per view is recommended for MVVM.

Answer (score 0):

There's no real hard and fast rules but essentially there's normally one ViewModel per View.  You can get into a situation where you want to share a view model across multiple views but it's rare.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine what you want to see on the screen and each state the screen / controls on the screen might be in, everything that is needed on that particular screen (view) should have a corresponding property in your ViewModel that you can bind the View to.  So, this translate to a single ViewModel for a particular View.  The ViewModel itself can be tied into one or more model(s) in the back.  At least that's how I understand it.